# Update xcode project with changes from Unity3d

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity3d project that I am releasing to both android and iOS, for the iOS build unity exports a xcode project which I can then open and build to submit to iTunes connect.

However to get the project submit-able I had to make quite a few changes to the xcode project before it would build (adding libraries, build flags etc etc).
This is fine to do once, however I am now ready to release an update to my project but would rather not have to completely set back up the xcode project with all my changes (certainly as I do not remember all the changes!).

Is there a way I can over write the Unity3d project in the xcode project, so all my xcode settings stay the same BUT the actually project is overwritten with the new unity data.

Answer (score 0):

Just select existing xcode project folder and append the build instead of replace when you click on Build.

Comment: Tried appending, seems I can only append ones, then strange things happens. Unity, da middleware, aye.

Comment: It usually happens when you cancel building process of Unity.